# Unable to import package in virtual environment using anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

I have installed a package in my virtual environment. The package is also listed in the conda list but when I try to import the package it returns an Import Error.

[image: terminal shot of pip list --local]

[image: terminal short of importing the package]

I was following the tutorial [here](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/)

Comment: in termainl try this from outside of the example_pg folder :)

Comment: I tried importing the package from outside the terminal. I got a ModuleNotFound error even though it is displayed as a package in virtual env.

Comment: is it a custom package? if yes then you need to check it's setup.py file and see what is the invocation word they used

Comment: Yes, it is a custom package.

Answer (score 1):

i just followed the whole tutorial,

first after creating the  structure (schema in the tutorial):

1 . in terminal open your env
2. run `python -m pip install --user --upgrade setuptools wheel`
3. `python setup.py sdist`
4. `python setup.py install`

then in terminal (virtual env activated )
run commands

`import example_pkg`

it will import it.